# Is there any short way of attaching pdf on wesite

Tags: c#

What can I do if I want to add a PDF book on my website so that  the user can be able to view . I am using C#

Comment: And what is your question? But first, be sure you have the rights to distribute the book.

Answer (score 2):

Add the pdf to your site and link to it with the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with this  library called [Js Pdf](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

Otherwise there is a hack which is very simple and easy, you can use a dynamic URL for the PDF book and an Iframe

```js
function showPDF()
{
viewFile('http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf') ;
}
     function viewFile(fileurl) {
                
   var    url = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url='+fileurl+'&embedded=true' ;
   
    var eframe = document.getElementById('frameviewfile');
     eframe.src= url;
    
                return false;
            }
```

```html
<button onClick="showPDF()">Show PDF File</button>
<iframe id="frameviewfile" height="800" width="1000" src="
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```